# Codeigniter session not being maintained after certain pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using PHP native session instead of CI session library.CI version ci-2.2.
When i login to admin, it sets the session.I can go to any next page which requires session.But when when i go to another page after that the session is lost.It works fine locally and on many other servers for which I use CI.

As an example.

I login to admin.It takes me to dashboard.Then i go to some listings page.It works fine.Thereafter I click on say some add new page , session is lost.

Answer (score 0):

if any of your controller extends the admin controller make sure the session check is done on the admin controller itself.
so that any controller that extend it will inherit the check.
Hope this helps.